Show 'Export' button instead of icon in Fusion chart
I am using Fusion charts in my Laravel project. I have used exportenabled: 1 and the export icon is showing. I want to change that icon to text "Export". I tried annotations but that doesn't work.
const employeeSegmentationChartConfigs = {
  type: "pie3d",
  width: "1000",
  height: "450",
  dataFormat: "json",
  dataSource: {
    "chart": {
      "use3DLighting": "0",
      "showPercentValues": "1",
      "decimals": "1",
      "useDataPlotColorForLabels": "1",
      "theme": "fusion",
      "exportenabled": "1",
      "exportfilename": "employeeSegmentationExport",
      "paletteColors": "#7d7d7d,#C70814,#450E76,#9C28B1,#16938E, #C3C146,#532DDF, #7BC82D"
    },
    "data": employeeSegmentationData
  }
}

